# Bound for expectation of product of dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are (real-valued) non-negative random variables with the same distribution and finite second moment, then $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ is maximal if $X=Y$ a.s., since $\mathbb{E}[XY]\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]} = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$ by Cauchy—Schwarz.

Now suppose I have some other non-negative random variable $Z$ (not necessarily with finite moments) and I have $\mathbb{E}[X^2Z]<\infty$ (but not necessarily $\mathbb{E}[Y^2Z]<\infty$). 
Do I then also have that $\mathbb{E}[XYZ] \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2 Z]$?
If $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$, this is easy, but what if we allow for dependence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this will be true **if** *(sufficient condition, not necessary)* $\mathbb{E}[X^2 Z  \mid Z]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2 Z  \mid Z]$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[XYZ] 
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XYZ\mid Z]] = \mathbb{E}[Z \mathbb{E}[XY \mid Z]]
\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[Z \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Z]\mathbb{E}[Y^2 \mid Z]}]
\stackrel{(\star)}{=} \mathbb{E}[Z \mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Z]]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X^2 Z  \mid Z]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[ X^2Z ]
\end{align}$$

However, it is **false** in general. Consider $X,Y$ two independent r.v.'s, uniform on $[0,1]$; and $Z = \mathbf{1}_{\{Y>1/2\}}$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[XYZ] 
= \mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{Y>1/2\}}] 
= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{8} = \frac{3}{16}\,;
$$
however,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2 Z] 
= \mathbb{E}[X^2]\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y>1/2\}}] 
= \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6} < \frac{3}{16}.
$$